# Tutorial for Browser plug-in development using IDL approach.

Tags: plugins, browser, idl, browser-plugin

i am new in IDL approach.
i need some good tutorial to understand this.

please can anyone share name of good books or some link.

thanks in adv :)

Comment: Do you mean the Interactive Data Language, or the Interface Definition Language?  (In short, what are you trying to do in the first place?)

Answer (score 1):

- Good resources online about IDL:

  1) [Corba IDL Intro](http://jmvidal.cse.sc.edu/csce590/spring02/corba-idl-intro.pdf).

  2) [Understanding Interface Definition Language: A Developer's Survival Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0898/idl/idl.aspx).

  3) [An introduction to programming with IDL](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=wNWHUS69DrcC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=idl%20language%20reference&source=bl&ots=Nj5EjHXZiQ&sig=fU6D0tvrY8Kah-RtRpY707yApuc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Eiz2UZLIKIKxrgfdsoHADg&ved=0CHAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=idl%20language%20reference&f=false).
- The good IDL books by author:

  1) Practical IDL programming (**By Liam E Gumley**).

  This is a good reference book and covers a large part of IDL language.

  **Website**: [www.gumley.com](http://www.gumley.com)

  2) IDL programming Techniques, Second Edition (**By David W. Fanning**) .

  This is also a relatively comprehensive book for IDL and is strong enough in understanding
   graphics outputs (GUI) and OOPS concepts.

  **Website**: [www.dfanning.com](http://www.dfanning.com)

  You can also find many examples, programs and data to download, learn and play at site:
  [LearnIDL](http://learnidl.com/).

The author is *Ken Bowman* and he is a professor in the Atmospheric Sciences Department at Texas A&M University who teaches IDL programming.

That's the all package for you.

Good Luck!

Comment: I believe the above is confusing Interactive Data Language with Interface Definition Language (which I believe the original author is asking about). Most of the resources listed are for the Interactive Data Language with the exception of the Corba IDL Intro.